# How do I validate if a date format has valid order and has valid directive in Python

Tags: python, validation, datetime

#### I would like to check if the string which is a date format is valid or not

I have a case where I pass a string which is a date format, `string = "%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S.%f%z"`. I need to verify if the given string is in correct order like %Y then %m then %d and so on and the string has valid directives.

Eg:

```
1. string = "%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S.%f%z"  <- correct
2. string = "%Y-%m-%d" <- correct
3. string = "%d-%m-%Y" <- correct
4. string = "%Y-%m-%o" <- incorrect as there is no Directive %o
```

the string has to take the valid directive in correct order. Some of the resource I referred: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior (gives a list of valid directives)

Comment: Since you already have the list of valid format specifiers, just check against the format you have, and see if the string is contained or not. Talking about the order, Python datetime format doesn't need any specific order, so you need to compare the values in the order you want.

Comment: You might be able to simply split using `%` and check if all adjacent characters are valid. Obviously a tiny bit more needs to be done, but this is the basis,.

Comment: Oh ok got it. I was thinking if we had some method that can verify the format and the directives for us.